# Flutter : Project Files Missing From IDE

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I'm having this issue across all my Flutter projects, thinking it was something wrong I did I opened the Flutter Gallery project but it turns out this problem is present on that project as well. I can't figure out what's wrong because the files for all the projects are there on my File Explorer yet do not display on my IDE. How do I go about correcting this because I do not have an idea at the moment. I've attached images for some visuals

[image: Android Studio]

[image: File Explorer]

On another post I saw that you need to change this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

To this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

But then this happens
[image]

And this

[image]

Something to note is that changing the UTF from 8 to 16 is inconsistent across projects. For my one project it worked but for this particular one it didn't because not only is it displaying the wrong class in my main.dart it also only shows half of that entire class. The HomePage is unreadable.  Some very weird behavior. Because of these inconsistencies I found that this 'solution' isn't the best hence I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: It looks like you open a file or (project file) in your existing project, that made Android Studio to open a new project (other type of project file that is applicable in Android Studio). Check on Recent projects if there is an entry of that new one.